# AngularJS view doesn't update when ng-model value changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Please check this codepen, when clicked on the button **click me to reset name**, the name input should be reset to empty, when I do `console.log` on the directive scope, I do see `name` is set to empty string, but the value in the view not get updated. What's wrong?

[CodePen example](http://codepen.io/yocoso/pen/PNRgJO)

```js
angular.module('mainApp', [])
  .directive('myTab', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: 'name: <input type="text" ng-model="name">',
      controller: function($location, $scope) {
        $scope.name = 'myname';
        $('#clickMeToReset').on('click', function() {
          $scope.name = '';
        })
      }
    };
  })
  .directive('myMenu', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<button id="clickMeToReset">click me to reset name</button>'
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="mainApp">
  <my-menu></my-menu>
  <my-tab></my-tab>
</div>
```

Comment: just add   ` $scope.$apply();` after resting  name variable

Answer (score 2):

After

```
$scope.name = '';
```

Do a

```
$scope.$apply();
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use other libraries like jquery in angular, changes to variables like 
 `$scope` should manually broadcast.

```
 $('#clickMeToReset').on('click', function(){
        $scope.name = '';
        $scope.$apply();
})
```

so `$scope.$apply();` will do the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Modify your controller code with the following:

```
controller: function($location,$scope, $timeout){
  $scope.name = 'myname';
  $('#clickMeToReset').on('click', function(){
    $timeout(function() {
       $scope.name = '';
    });
  })
}
```

```js
angular.module('mainApp', [])
  .directive('myTab', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: 'name: <input type="text" ng-model="name">',
      controller: function($location, $scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.name = 'myname';
        $('#clickMeToReset').on('click', function() {
          $timeout(function() {
            $scope.name = '';
          });
        })
      }
    };
  })
  .directive('myMenu', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<button id="clickMeToReset">click me to reset name</button>'
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="mainApp">
  <my-menu></my-menu>
  <my-tab></my-tab>
</div>
```

Since you are using jQuery to change the value, which is out of the Angular's context, so Angular is unaware of the change. So you need to tell Angular that something has changed. So we are using `$timeout` service to achieve this. We can also use `$scope.$apply()` but that may fail when the digest cycle is already in progress.

### Important

You should use `ng-click` instead and remove dependency of jQuery if possible since jQuery is also a big library in itself like Angular (**see a working example below**):

```js
angular.module('mainApp', [])
  .directive('myTab', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: 'name: <input type="text" ng-model="name">',
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.name = 'myname';
        $scope.clearName = function() {
          $scope.name = '';
        }
      }
    };
  })
  .directive('myMenu', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<button ng-click="clearName()">click me to reset name</button>'
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="mainApp">
  <my-menu></my-menu>
  <my-tab></my-tab>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way can ng-click in myMenu directive change the variable in myTab directive

Comment: Yes @user1735940. It's possible. See my updated answer with a working example.

Answer (score 0):

I hope According to my thinking this code help you . Only change Js code remaining HTML code is proper.

```js
   var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', []);
   mainApp.directive('myTab', function() {
   return {
    template: 'name: <input type="text" ng-model="name">',
    controller: function($location,$scope){ debugger;
      $scope.name = 'myname';
      $('#clickMeToReset').on('click', function(){
        $scope.name = '';
      })
    }
  };
})
.directive('myMenu', function() {
  return {
    name:"clickMeReset",
    template: '<button id="name" ng-click="clear()">click me to reset name</button>',
    controller:
    function($location,$scope){
      $('#name').on('click',       function(){
        $scope.name = '';
      })
    }
  };
});
```